# Android Studio creating old version of application

Tags: react-native, android-studio, build, android-build

When am creating build using android studio getting  old version of application all the time. For  get rid out of this I deleted build folder and  inside assets index.android.bundle, but still getting older version of build.

I also tried:

1. Restarting Android Studio
2. Restarting PC
3. Restarting Device
4. Sync Project
5. Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstall app from device and pre-generate a new bundle before starts the android studio build

```
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the build folders (and release) `rm -rf {root}/build && {root}/app/build|release/`

Then clean: `cd android && ./gradlew clean build`  You can also use the flag `--no-build-cache` to omit the build cache on next build